# Reading the user input from the console & writing it to JSON

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

I'm a newb to Java programming. What I wanted to do was, read the inputs from the console & then write it to JSON, after which I'll be persisting the data in JSON to the database.

I have written a class UserInput, which reads user Input as follows:

```
package com.mmk.vo;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;

public class UserInput {

    private String firstName,lastName,email, mobile;

    public String UserInput() {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name;");
        String firstName = sc.next();

        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your lastName;");
        String lastName = sc1.next();

        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your email;");
        String email = sc2.next();

        Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your mobile;");
        String mobile = sc3.next();

        return "UserInput [fisrtName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + ", mobile="
        + mobile + "]";

    }
}
```

I have written a method in my main class, in which I have given some default values & what this does is writes these default values to the DB.

```
    static UserInput jsonToDB(){
    String json = "{"
            + "firstName: \"Arsene\","
            + "lastName: \"Wenger\","
            + "mobile: \"1234\","
            + "email: \"test@test.com\""    
            + "}";

    Gson g = new Gson();
    UserInput user = g.fromJson(json, UserInput.class);

    //System.out.println(user);
    return user;
}
```

Now, I want the user Input from the console to be witten into the JSON. Could someone guide me how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to write json to console on System.out.println(user);  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**Try this just copy and paste it in your public class**

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name;");
        String firstName = sc.next();
        myMap.put("firstName",firstName);


        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your lastName;");
        String lastName = sc1.next();
        myMap.put("lastName",lastName);

        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your email;");
        String email = sc2.next();
        myMap.put("email",email);

        Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your mobile;");
        String mobile = sc3.next();
        myMap.put("mobile",mobile);


        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(myMap.toString());
            System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

> You have to import
>       import org.json.JSONException;
>       import org.json.JSONObject;
>       import java.util.HashMap;
>       import java.util.Map;

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot that could be improved about your code but to address the main question:

In your UserInput class you have declared attributes on the class that you do not set in the 'UserInput' method.  You UserInput method should probably be renamed to something like 'readUser' because 'UserInput' would typically indicate a constructor method for the UserInput class.

So I'd suggest change the name of your UserInput method and make it static.  Also make it construct a new UserInput object and set the values it reads from the console onto the attributes of that new UserInput object - as follows:

```
public static UserInput readUser() {

     UserInput userInput = new UserInput(); //construct a new UserInput instance

     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter your name;");
     userInput.firstName = sc.next();  // set the value read from console as a property on the UserInput instance

     ... etc.

     return userInput;  // return the instance of UserInput object that we just created.


}
```

Then in your jsonToDb() method - take a 'UserInput' object as an argument:
i.e.

```
public static UserInput jsonToDb(UserInput userInput) {

    Gson g = new Gson();

    String json = userInput.toJson(userInput);

    .....
    UserInput user = g.fromJson(json, UserInput.class);

}
```

or alternately don't pass a UserInput object in - read it from the console using your static method:

```
public static UserInput jsonToDb() {

    UserInput userInput = UserInput.readUser();
    Gson g = new Gson();

    String json = userInput.toJson(userInput);

    .....
    UserInput user = g.fromJson(json, UserInput.class);

}
```